Can I run electrical PVC conduit through rigid foam wall insulation?
I am running PVC conduit for a 60 amp car charger through an exterior wall containing rigid foam insulation under the vinyl siding. I read the electrical PVC conduit cannot be surrounded by thermal insulation in the wall cavity, but is it safe to run the pvc conduit through the rigid foam insulation in the exterior wall?

I'm thinking thermal insulation includes rigid foam, so no.  However a work around may be to use a larger conduit, like a 2 inch through the hole and run the conduit for the wire through that.  Then the electrical conduit is NOT surrounded by thermal insulation.

1 - Are you running it just through a few inches - i.e., literally from inside to outside? Or are you running it several feet - i.e., inside a wall from point a to point b along the wall? In the first case I think this is a non-issue. 2 - Do you actually need 60A? Do you have enough capacity to actually add 60A of charging?

Nearly all meter base and panel passthroughs (and even roof drops) are within and in contact with wall and/or attic insulation. I think we have a misinterpretation of the intent of any such rule here.
